# Couldn't resolve resource @style.AppTheme.AppBarOverlay

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-theme

I am getting a conflict between toolbar designs and a rendering problem in my xml editor.

I want to render the toolbar design, but it looks like it has already been rendered and I can't find where.

Here is the java activity class. I am getting an error at `line 21` where `setSupportActionBar` is called:

```
public class NoteActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_note);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        Spinner spinnerCourses = findViewById(R.id.spinner_courses);

        List<CourseInfo> courses = DataManager.getInstance().getCourses();
        ArrayAdapter<CourseInfo> adapterCourses =
                new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapterCourses.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spinnerCourses.setAdapter(adapterCourses);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_note, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Here is my `styles.xml` file:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

</resources>
```

..and here is my activity layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.emmanuelani.notekeeper.NoteActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_note"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I am getting the following error:

```
08-30 15:00:14.783 32595-32595/com.emmanuelani.notekeeper E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.emmanuelani.notekeeper, PID: 32595
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.emmanuelani.notekeeper/com.emmanuelani.notekeeper.NoteActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2613)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1517)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:227)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6102)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:859)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:345)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:130)
        at com.emmanuelani.notekeeper.NoteActivity.onCreate(NoteActivity.java:21)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6280)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1131)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2566)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1517) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:227) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6102) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:859) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should check AndroidManifest.xml file in which which style you have  applied to activity in which you are facing issue.

If you have applied "AppTheme" theme then you should try "AppTheme.NoActionBar" or if you have not added theme it'll by default pick up "AppTheme" so you have to change activity theme to "AppTheme.NoActionBar" in AndroidManifest.xml

Also add change your "AppTheme.NoActionBar" theme as below and apply this theme in AndroidManifest.xml to "NoteActivity".

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I added @style/AppTheme.NoActionBar to the `activity` tag in the manifest. Still no changes. It became red.

Comment: I just came across this issue. Problem was that values/styles.xml was holding not the string that I expected under "AppTheme". So make sure that in your case "AppTheme.NoActionBar" exists in your styles file.